# Chrome Remote Desktop AUDIO - Windows server to Ubuntu and Android clients

Tags: sound, google-chrome, remote-desktop, streaming

What audio encoding does Chrome Remote Desktop use? It seems to be streaming audio quite smoothly but I want to know if it is audiophile quality. VLC Media Player, for instance, streams FLAC over HTTP but with higher latency.

Does anybody know?

Comment: I do not see that as a Ubuntu question.

Comment: At the time of asking it was (for me) because I could not stream audio with VLC Media Player from Linux, only from Windows. I had to use Chrome RD for Linux and I was trying to decide if the lossy sound quality was worth it (i.e. ditching Windows). However, I just found a solution today, where I can stream FLAC from Linux to Linux. https://superuser.com/questions/605445/how-to-stream-my-gnu-linux-audio-output-to-android-devices-over-wi-fi/1021823#1021823?newreg=837f60244c0b4046af7c6cbbb0d8c300